# Cocos 2D, why lags when moving objects?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm developing a game, obviously there are moving objects... when I move them they lag. My colleague has the same problems
Thus I move obstacle:

```
-(void)moveThings:(ccTime)dt 
{
    CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    for(CCSprite * sprite in visibleObstacle)
    {
        if(sprite.position.x<=size.width)
        {
            sprite.position=ccp(sprite.position.x-2, sprite.position.y);
        }
        else
        {
            [self removeChild:sprite cleanup:YES];
            [visibleObstacle removeObject:sprite];
        }
    }


}
```

Thus I move plane:

```
-(void)manageFlight
{

    [plane runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.05 position:ccp(plane.position.x, plane.position.y-2)]];
    //self.bgLayer.position=CGPointMake(self.bgLayer.position.x-1, self.bgLayer.position.y);
    //self.bgTrees.position=CGPointMake(self.bgTrees.position.x-5, self.bgTrees.position.y);

}
```

ALso I move background which is tile.. well when I move obstacle for instance they happen to lag, even if sprites are small. any advice? Are there other reliable frameworks for games on iphone? thanks

Comment: How much does your framerate drop to ?
are u creating many objects ?

Comment: Solved the problem a long time ago)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It look like removing sprites causes your lags. You should just hide it or/and to reposition as you want. 
As following:

```
 if(sprite.position.x<=size.width)
    {
        sprite.position=ccp(sprite.position.x-2, sprite.position.y);
    }
    else
    {
        [sprite setPosition:ccp(-sprite.contentSize.width, sprite.position.y]; 
    }
```

Comment: I asked this question several months ago, the thing was to put all of the sprites in the atlas. But I no longer occupy with game development for a while